# Dynamically change element styles via custom properties?

Tags: css, polymer

For example, you can change the `ink` colour in `paper-tabs` by changing `--paper-tab-ink: var(--accent-color);`. Is it possible to change the value of the CSS custom properties dynamically similar to how you can toggle a class or change the style in JS?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this, but a simple answer is to use the Polymer.updateStyles() method after making your class changes.

For example, let's say your styles are:

```
<style>
.yellow x-example {
  --light-primary-color: #fdd85f;
}
.red x-example {
  --light-primary-color: red;
}
</style>
```

and you want to make the  component use the styles in the .red class. You simply add it as you normally would in javascript, then be sure to also use this function to actually update it on the page.

```
<div class="yellow" onclick="this.className='red'; Polymer.updateStyles()">
  <x-example></x-example>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first get the object of your custom element. Then get the customStyle object. Add a style to that object. And then run element.updateStyles();

```
       t.clickListener= function(e) {
           var t = Polymer.dom(e).localTarget; //retarget if needed
           t.customStyle['--the-color-etc'] = 'pink';
           t.updateStyles(); // mandatory for the CSS variables shim
       };
```

See [the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-api)